Discrepancy in RPS between custom Golang load generator and other tools
I'm working on a load generator written in Golang, and I'm currently using the Resty library to handle HTTP requests. The main logic of my load generator is fairly simple: I start goroutines that run specific "scenarios" and make HTTP requests with a delay between them.
For monitoring, I count the total number of HTTP requests made. However, I've noticed a significant discrepancy in the requests per second (RPS) between my load generator and other standard tools. While the standard tools report a high RPS, my implementation seems to cap at around 80 RPS, which is not even comparable.
Am I missing something related to the specifics of the HTTP client implementation in Resty or Go in general that could be causing this performance ceiling?
I initially thought that the issue might be related to the active HTTP connections or some specifics of the Resty HTTP client implementation in Go. To troubleshoot, I replaced Resty with the standard net/http package, but there was no difference in the RPS.

Without code we cant help
